# Raw file name is unknown when upload video to Youtube through API

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using C# language to post videos in Youtube using API. Everything is working fine , videos get uploaded with titles , descriptions, tags , thumbnails. But each file i upload have Raw file name unknown. I am using Youtube API v3. There is no documentation for raw filename in YouTube API

I tried fileDetails with video but not works.

Here is code i am using.

```
var video = new Video();
video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
video.Snippet.Title = title;
if (isIncludeTitleInDesc)
    desc = desc + "  " + title;
video.Snippet.Description = desc;
video.Snippet.Tags = tags;
video.Snippet.CategoryId = categoryId; 
video.Status = new VideoStatus();
video.Status.PrivacyStatus = isPublic ? "public" : "private";  
video.Snippet.Thumbnails = new ThumbnailDetails();

try
{
    var videosInsertRequest = youtube.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", stream, "video/*");
    videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += insertRequest_ProgressChanged;
    videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += insertRequest_ResponseReceived;

    IUploadProgress result = videosInsertRequest.Upload();
    if (result.Status == UploadStatus.Completed)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: "I tried fileDetails with video but not works." That's very unclear - please show exactly what you tried, and what happened. And what *exactly* do you mean by "have raw file name unknown"? The clearer you can be about the problem, the easier it will be to help you - and the more useful your question will be for future visitors.

Comment: I think you have forgotten videosInsertRequest.Execute()  you are uploading the file but not inserting the actual metadata for the video.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo for replying, I have used Execute method in Progresschanged handler. Actually video is uploading, there is no problem in uploading video. When we go to youtube, we check the details how many likes dislikes, there is one field Raw Name which is video file name. In our case this Raw File Name is unknown. Please let me know if my description not meets.

Comment: @SandeepChadgal i think your going to have to show a better description of your problem.    I dont understand what you mean by raw file name.   If its the name of a video then its one your uploaded probably.    There is no field in the video resource called raw file name so i dont really know what you mean about it being null https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource

Comment: @DaImTo here is what i need http://prntscr.com/hbrg7g)  True there is no property in video reserource for raw file name but some apps i tried they are uploading raw file name as name of video file. Can you help me with how i can set video file name as raw name as shown in link.

Comment: to my knowledge this is not something you can set in the library

Comment: There are paid softwares doing it, uploading raw file name using Youtube API. I will comment here when i find an answer

Comment: @DalmTo i dont know why you marked this as duplicate, that question have different idea.